# How to run program in vb.net without the solution file?

Tags: vb.net

Currently I have a .vb file only and the debugging button shows "Attach" instead of "Start". How do I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could compile and run it from the command line. You can't directly execute the source code. Or you can create a new project and visual studio and include the code in it. Note you don't technically need a solution file for it to work in visual studio, only a project file would be needed

Comment: If the `.vb` file has only classes/methods inside, you just need to include it in an existing or a new project. Put it inside the Project folder, in Solution Explorer select the button `Show all files`, then right-click and `Include in Project`.

Comment: I got it, I created a new project then include`.vb` file inside it. Thank you for the help Adyson & Jimi